# Geolocation watchPosition. How to get one event when location reached?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm working on an WebApp for mobile users, which have do go to predefined location and at first can see there a `<div>` (text, picture, or whatever).
So, I've one predefined location and the current user location. If both locations are equal, I'll show something.
How can I do it? This code is not working:

```
var id, ziel, options;
//Verfolgen beginnen
id = navigator.geolocation.watchCurrentPosition(verfolgePosition);

function verfolgePosition(pos) {
  var aktuell = pos.coords;

  if (ziel.latitude === aktuell.latitude && ziel.longitude === aktuell.longitude) {
    console.log('Sie haben Ihr Ziel erreicht');
    //Verfolgen beenden
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
  }
}

ziel = {
  latitude : 0,
  longitude: 0
};

options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};
```

by the way, the goal can be:

```
ziel = {
  latitude : 52.514971,
  longitude: 13.369172
};
```

Comment: There is no method `watchCurrentPosition()`. What you're looking for is `.watchPosition()` [w3](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#watch-position)/[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition)

Comment: Yes ist true. I changed it to '.watchPosition' but it worked only once. Maybe because the movable location(mobile device) changes to fast to get the exact fixed position, also if I test this script at the same position. How can i fix it?

Comment: From the w3 link in my comment: "_In step 5.2.2 of the watch process, **the successCallback is only invoked** when a new position is obtained and this **position differs significantly from the previously reported position**. The definition of what constitutes a significant difference is left to the implementation. **Furthermore, in steps 5.2.2 and 5.2.3, implementations may impose limitations on the frequency of callbacks so as to avoid inadvertently consuming a disproportionate amount of resources**._"

Comment: As I understand, my test doesn't work at fixed position?

Comment: Can someone else help me with this issue? Maybe another solution, different code?

Answer (score 0):

```
var id, target, options;

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  if (target.latitude === crd.latitude && target.longitude === crd.longitude) {
    console.log('Congratulations, you reached the target');
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
  }
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
}

target = {
  latitude : 0,
  longitude: 0
};

options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

For more info read
[Geolocation.watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition)